# Python - Comparing strings from a file

Tags: python, string, file

I'm just learning Python to make extensions in Inkscape, and I'm having an issue with comparing strings that I loaded from a file. What I'm trying to do is to load a polygon that I have defined in a text file:

```
    polygon
    r:255
    g:0
    b:0
    50;50
    50;100
    100;50
```

My parsing method is such:

```
    def load_file(filepath, parent, log):
        file = open(filepath)
        x = []
        y = []
        r = 0
        g = 0
        b = 0
        index = 0

        for line in file:
            fline = line.lstrip("\xef\xbb\xbf").rstrip("\n")
            log.write("Input string: " + repr(line) + "\n")
            log.write("Formatted: " + repr(fline) + "\n")
            if fline == "":
                continue
            elif fline is "polygon": ## Where the first line should be going
                log.write("\tDetected string as polygon start delimiter\n")
                if index > 0:
                    draw_shape(x, y, r, g, b, "Polygon", parent)
                    del x[0, len(x)]
                    del y[0, len(y)]
                    r = g = b = index = 0
                continue
            elif fline[:2] is "r:":
                log.write("\tDetected string as polygon red value delimiter\n")
                r = int(fline[2:])
                continue
            elif fline[:2] is "g:":
                log.write("\tDetected string as polygon green value delimiter\n")
                g = int(fline[2:])
                continue
            elif fline[:2] is "b:":
                log.write("\tDetected string as polygon blue value delimiter\n")
                b = int(fline[2:])
                continue
            else: ## Where the first line actually is going
                log.write("\tDelimiter failed previous detections; assumed to be polygon cordinates\n")
                spl = fline.split(";")
                x[index] = float(spl[0]) ## Error gets thrown here
                y[index] = float(spl[1])
                index += 1
                continue

        draw_shape(x, y, r, g, b, parent)
```

This method is tripping up on the first line. It keeps seeing "polygon" and going to the final else block, where it parses the coordinates. The log file I'm keeping throughout looks like this:

```
    Process Started
    Input string: '\xef\xbb\xbfpolygon\n'
    Formatted: 'polygon'
        Delimiter failed previous detections; assumed to be polygon coordinates
```

I've stepped through the process in the shell and in there it says `line is "process"` is true, so I am completely lost here. Any help?

Comment: Don't use `is` to compare with anything except `None`. (use `==` to compare for equality).

Comment: @Wooble I think I'm going to shoot someone in the face... I knew it was something stupid like that. Mind putting that in an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The comparison `fline is "polygon"` will almost always be false. Use `fline == "polygon"` instead.
2. It’s unrelated to your problem, but you’ll have an easier time processing the text if you use the proper Unicode decoding functions, instead of manually stripping the byte order mark and treating the rest as bytes. I prefer `codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8-sig')`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have opened the Unicode file successfully, I think something like this is easier than what you are doing:

```
elements='''polygon
r:255
g:0
b:0
50;50
50;100
100;50

polygon
r:155
g:22
b:55
55;60
66;100
120;150
155;167'''       

for element in re.split(r'^\s*\n',elements,flags=re.MULTILINE):
    if element.startswith('polygon'):
        el=element.splitlines()
        poly={k:v for k,v in [s.split(':') for s in el[1:4]]}
        x,y=zip(*[s.split(';') for s in el[4:]])
        poly.update({'x':x, 'y': y})
        print poly
```

Prints:

```
{'y': ('50', '100', '50'), 'x': ('50', '50', '100'), 'r': '255', 'b': '0', 'g': '0'}
{'y': ('60', '100', '150', '167'), 'x': ('55', '66', '120', '155'), 'r': '155', 'b': '55', 'g': '22'}
```

Comment: Not really sure what I am looking at here.

Comment: You can now do this: `draw_shape(poly['x'], poly['y'], poly['r'], poly['g'], poly['b'], ...)`

Comment: Well, I understand that this function basically comes up with a polygon object that is a dictionary holding tuples in the keys that correspond to values in the text file, but as to how it's doing that, all I can guess is that it looks similar to LINQ.